# pygame display boots up then immediately shuts down

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to display something but it keeps booting up and immediately quitting.

the console comes up with:

```py
 line 77, in main
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
NameError: name 'MOUSEBUTTONDOWN' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last): line 89, in <module>
    main()
```

but I didn't think any of these problems would create this but I'm not sure.

```py
def main(): #main game loop
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                clicking = True

        draw_window(startbutton, exitbutton,)


    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The `event` object must be checked within the event loop. Also use `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` instead of `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`:

```py
ef main(): #main game loop
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        
        # INDENTATION
        #-->|
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    clicking = True

        draw_window(startbutton, exitbutton,)


    pygame.quit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` instead of just a `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. Same as in `pygame.QUIT`.